# Visual studio 2017 - IDE black parts

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, ide

Some areas in Visual Studio 2017 are black(not refreshed) when i open it or i swich tabs. Text is showed again if i select it.

[image]

The biggest issue is in aspx files - it shows previous aspx file. When i hover over some menu options its fixed for that menu. Or if i change size of window its fixed but some areas stays black - line numbers.

[image]

Comment: Check out this thread. Seems like a similar issue. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/133959/ui-not-rendering-properly.html

Comment: @Impurity you can post it as an asnwer it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try following [this Microsoft](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/133959/ui-not-rendering-properly.html) thread to rectify the issues with the IDE.